# How can I set the action "on delete set null" to a foreign key with JPA

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa

In my entity class I have a column defined like this:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="foo_id", nullable=true, updatable=true, foreignKey=@ForeignKey(name="fk_foo_fee"))
private Foo foo;
```

Today I checked the properties of the foreign key `fk_foo_fee` on pgAdmin and found out that its action is `on delete no action`. The problem is that the action must be on `delete set null`. pgAdmin doesn't let me change it with its interface. So how can I change it with JPA?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
child.setParent(null);
session.delete(parent);
```

You should also be able to put it in a PreRemove:

```
@PreRemove
private void preRemove() {
    // set foo to null here
}
```